# BadRequestImageFormat error while trying to post an image attachment to Custom Vision API using NodeJS bot

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

```
var request = require('request'); //node module for http post requests

exports.retreiveMessage = function (session){

request.post({
    url: 'https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v1.0/Prediction/279ae65a-c1f8-4eb0-a4d8-03a3234bc023/image?iterationId=bcfb842f-df51-47e3-8ba4-c90209a16003',
    json: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Prediction-Key': 'XXXXX'
    },
    body: session.message.attachments[0]
}, function(error, response, body){
    if (error){
        console.log(error);
    }

    console.log(validResponse(body));
    session.send(validResponse(body));
});
}

function validResponse(body){
if (body && body.Predictions && body.Predictions[0].Tag){
    return "This is " + body.Predictions[0].Tag
} else{
    console.log('Oops, please try again! Something is wrong with custom vision.');
}
}
```

This is the block of code that I'm trying to use to post an image attachment to Custom Vision API, but I keep getting BadRequestImageFormat and I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hi @yfan183, is there any update?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I still wasn't able to solve it but I think it had a lot of things to do with the rest of my code as well

Comment: OK, looking forward to your good news.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I've already scrapped this part of code from my project, meanwhile I was hoping if you can help with my LUIS questions that I just posted recently...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the reference part of **request body** is not clear at the [documentation](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/eb68250e4e954d9bae0c2650db79c653/operations/58acd3c1ef062f0344a42814), but we can from the c# code sample at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/use-prediction-api, that we need to post the image binary in `body` property.

And in Bot Framework, the `session.message.attachments[0]` is an object with the attachments info not content in buffer type:
[image]
which rised your issue.

Please try following code snippet:

```
        const rp = require('request-promise');
        rp.get(session.message.attachments[0].contentUrl).then(buffer=>{
            return rp.post(
                {
                    url:<url>,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                        'Prediction-Key': '<key>'
                    },
                    body: buffer
                }
            )
        }).then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            session.send(res)
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove `json: true`.

Comment: removed it did solve the problem, but now I'm getting "Error: Argument error, options.body" and "TypeError: first argument must be a string or buffer" at _http_outgoing.js now, any idea on what this is?

Comment: Check the code in the callback function. For example you're doing console.log of a console.log